# How to insert a range of numbers into sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3
connector = sqlite3.connect("Database_1.db") 
cursor = connector.cursor()
def Table_making():
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tester(Tester_1 INT)")
def data_entry():
    for x in range(1,10):
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Tester(Tester_1) VALUES(?)", x)
    connector.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connector.close()
Table_making()
data_entry()
```

As you can see I am trying to insert a range of numbers from (0,10) to Table_1, but I continuously run into this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can i get around this error and insert the range of numbers?

Comment: you say numbers (0,10) but put (1,10) in your code. are you aware that range(1,10) will yield you in total 9 items  `>>> list(range(10)
... )
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
` ?

Comment: @zython yes I am aware, and it's all right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second argument of [`executemany`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) needs to be iterable (i.e. it will do the looping for you):

```
def data_entry():
    data = ( (i, ) for i in range(1, 10) )
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Tester(Tester_1) VALUES(?)", data)
    ....
```

should do. note that each entry in the second argument (when iterating over) needs to be a `tuple`. therefore the 1-tuple `(i, )` in the `data` generator.

Comment: Your code shows error every time I change anything above 10. Any numbers below 10 are working

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `executemany` is an iterable (per row to execute) of iterables (per parameters). So the correct syntax is:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Tester(Tester_1) VALUES(?)", ((x,) for x in range(1, 10)))
cursor.close()
connector.commit()
```